# Finding Value of Expression in a Triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math

Kindly advise how do we solve this type of question. So far we know that it is a right-angled triangle. Thank you

[image]

Let *ABC* be a triangle with area 30. Let *D* be any point in its interior and let *e, f* and *g* denote the distances from D to the sides of the triangle. What is the value of the expression $5e+12f+13g$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area of the big triangle is the sum of
$$13\cdot g+(12-e)f+2ef+(5-f)e=60$$
so $$12g+5e+12f=60$$

Comment: still not clear about 132. g? Which formula or rule are you using?

Comment: Sorry it must be $$13\cdot g$$ i use that $$A=\frac{g\cdot h_g}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$5e$ is twice the area of $\triangle ACD$,so does the others.Therefore $5e+12f+13g$ is twice the area of $\triangle ABC$,which is 60.

Answer (score 0):

How do you "know" $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle? Is it a given?

If you're actually told that it's a $5-12-13$ right triangle as depicted, then just decompose the triangle into the smaller triangles $\triangle ADC, \triangle ADB$ and $\triangle CDB$, each of which has the respective area $\frac 12(5e), \frac 12 (13g)$ and $\frac 12(12f)$. The sum of these is obviously $30$, so you get $5e + 12f + 13g = 30$.

(To answer the confusion in the comment - the smaller triangles are *not* right triangles, nor do they have to be. The area of *any* triangle is half times the base times the height, and that's what's being applied here. For instance, in $\triangle ADC$, the height is $e$ while the base is $5$).

Comment: Using Pythagora's theorem, we can determine AB. Hence, △ ABC is a right-angled triangle.I am not clear how do you know after decomposing them into smaller triangles, they will be all right-angled triangles?

Comment: @Vyas If you're told a triangle is $5-12-13$, you know automatically that it's a right triangle (this is the converse of Pythagoras). Alternatively, if you're told that it's a right triangle with shorter sides of $5$ & $12$, then you know the hypotenuse is $13$ (that's just Pythagoras). But that wasn't my question. When you phrased the question, you said, "Let ABC be a triangle with area $30$". That seems redundant to me if you already know it's a right $5-12-13$ triangle, since it's trivial to calculate the area. Also, the smaller triangles are *not* right triangles, nor do they have to be.

Comment: @Vyas Edited my answer to clarify that confusion you had about the smaller triangles.